# Calculate score for a quiz on android

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am doing a `quiz`, in that I have 3 activities `Question1`, `Question2`, `Question3`,and on each there is 4 possible answers (buttons), only one button is correct. I must calculate and display the score of the user at the end of the quiz.

I have done some research and `SHAREDPREFERENECES` seem to be the solution. But i dont know how to use it can anyone help please. `Question1.java` code is below: Assume that `btnAnswer1a` is the correct answer, how do i save the data and then display it in a `textview` in the last activity.

```
 Button Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4;
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
 static SharedPreferences settings;
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 int ScoreCount;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.answer1);

  settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  editor = settings.edit();

  ScoreCount = settings.getInt("ScoreCount", 10);

   Answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1a);
   Answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1b);
   Answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1c);
   Answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1d);

   Answer1.setOnClickListener(this);
   Answer2.setOnClickListener(this);
   Answer3.setOnClickListener(this);
   Answer4.setOnClickListener(this);

         }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (arg0.getId()) {


    case R.id.btnAnswer1a:
          Intent Screen1 = new Intent(Answer1.this, Color2.class); 
          Answer1.this.startActivity(Screen1); 
          editor.putInt("ScoreCount", 6);
          editor.commit();
        break;


case R.id.btnAnswer1b:
      Intent Screen = new Intent(Answer1.this, Color2.class); 
    Answer1.this.startActivity(Screen);  
    break;

case R.id.btnAnswer1c:
      Intent Screen3 = new Intent(Answer1.this, Color2.class); 
    Answer1.this.startActivity(Screen3);  
    break;

case R.id.btnAnswer1d:
    Intent Screen2 = new Intent(Answer1.this, Color2.class); 
    Answer1.this.startActivity(Screen2);  
   break;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to write something to SharedPreferences use this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("your_name_of_shared_preferences", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.putInt("result", resultValue);
editor.commit();
```

And to read something from them just do this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("your_name_of_shared_preferences", 0);
int result = sharedPreferences.getInt("result", defaultValue);
```

resultValue is your quiz result and defaultValue is needed in situation when you didn't write anything to sharedPreferences under that key.

Comment: You write the value to sharedPreferences (the first part of code) when user answered the question of your quiz. S in your case in every activity. You get the value from sharedPreferences when you want to display the result, so i guess in the last activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you pass the information with the go in intent.  You can do so by:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.yourPackage.yourActivity");
i.putExtra("keyForExtra", _ID);
startActivity(i);
```

and onCreate of the resultant activity you can

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyForExtra");
```

You can parse this string to integer or whatever you feel like.

However if you are to do it with shared preferences, then, for writing:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_CUSTOM_PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("myScore", yourScore); // you can put a lot of thngs there. 
editor.commit();
```

To find out what else you can put look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_CUSTOM_PREFS_NAME, 0);
int currentScore = settings.getInt("myScore", defaultValue);
```

For detailed storage documentation of shared prefs look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: I have a problem. when a button is pressed another activity appears for 3 seconds, not the activity that i will pass the value. If i put that code Intent i = new Intent("com.yourPackage.yourActivity");
i.putExtra("keyForExtra", _ID);
startActivity(i); the activity that should appear for 3seconds will not work.

Comment: I dont understand the problem. You have to recover the score in the resultant activity. If the resultant activity displays for only 3 seconds and then starts another activity itself, pass this recovered score there. For this, you may want to make the recovered score variable an instance variable.

Comment: Its not the resultant activity that display 3 seconds. There is an image which appear for only 3 seconds, and next an activity open asking the user what he saw. Then while clicking on the right button, the score should scrore or incremented

Comment: Where are you showing the image? Can you please specify the flow diagram of how things are working? Of what I understand is: There is an activity in which an image is shown for 3seconds & then user is asked to input of what he saw. Input is required on the same activity. On input, the whole process repeats with score increment/decrement as required. If this is the case, in the 1st activity set score to 0. Make it an instance variable. Then pass it to next activity, retrive it there, store in an instance varibale, after getting the ansewer, update it and pass it through. Repeat untill needed

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you'd want a different activity for each question? It seems pretty inefficient to me (redundant code, error prone, memory wise). You could store all questions and answers inside arrays and keep track of the current question and score using ints. When a question is answered, check the answer, update the score, increment the current question, fetch the new question and answers and set those to the question textfield and button labels. No need for passing the score that way as everything remains inside one activity.

Comment: There is an image which appear for only 3 seconds, and next an activity open asking the user what he saw. Then while clicking on the right button, the score should scrore or incremented. Yes, redundant code, error prone and memory wise. I dont know how to do it in using array.